# How to grant a privilege to a role in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, roles, privileges

I need to grant a read privilege for the entire database (BH888) to a the role BH888.ROLE1. However, I need to make sure that any owner of the role BH888.ROLE1 cannot grant the same privileges to another role or user.

I then need to do the same for the role BH888.ROLE2, but this time I need to make sure that any owner owner of the role BH888.ROLE2 CAN grant the same privileges to another role or user.

Here is my code so far:

```
GRANT SELECT ON BH888.* TO BH5888.ROLE1; 

GRANT SELECT ON BH888.* TO BH5888.ROLE2;
```

I'm very new to MYSQL so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think that the user you've created has `GRANT`  permissions?

Comment: @NicoHaase IF they do get the GRANT permissions, I don't want them to be able to grant the same permissions to another user. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you plan to give users the `GRANT` permission if they should not use it? Why do they need it then?